# how to improve the performance of reading bytes line by line from a filestream

Tags: c#, .net, performance, file

I have a file bigger than 10G. 
To read this file line by line, I wrote this function.

```
static IEnumerable<string> fread(string fname, Encoding enc) 
  using (var f = File.OpenRead(fname))
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(f, enc))
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      yield return reader.ReadLine();     
}
```

This code works pretty well, but it returns a line string, not a line byte[].
So to return byte[] for each line, I wrote another function.

```
static IEnumerable<byte[]> freadbytes(string fname) {
  using (var f = File.OpenRead(fname)) {
    var bufSz = 1024;
    var buf = new byte[bufSz];
    var read = 1;
    var cr = (byte)13; // \r
    var lf = (byte)10; // \n
    var data = new List<byte>();
    while (read > 0) {
      read = f.Read(buf, 0, bufSz);
      data.AddRange(read == bufSz ? buf : buf.slc(0, read));
      var i = data.IndexOf(lf);
      while (i >= 0) {
        if (i > 0 && data[i - 1] == cr) yield return data.Take(i - 1).ToArray();
        else yield return data.Take(i).ToArray();
        data.RemoveRange(0, i + 1);
        i = data.IndexOf(lf);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The second function, freadbytes(), also works well, but the problem is that the second function takes more than 10 times of the first function.
To make the second function faster, what can I do?

Comment: Is this a text file, or a binary file? If it's text, why do you want the bytes? If it's binary, why are you looking for line breaks?

Comment: Binary will not speed up tremendously if you are consuming by lines. Not saying you can't speed it up in binary, but the concept of lines is related to text, not bytes.

Comment: This is a text file, but it contains some Korean characters. To parse each line, I should split the line based on bytes count using a given data spec. I had tried to parse with the line string, but due to the Korean characters, the bytes lengths are not matched with string lengths.

Comment: It seems that using the given data spec, I should decode some parts of a line as ASCII, while other parts of a line as ANSI or Korean Character set. I don't know whether this is a good way to do this. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @tk: It sounds like you need to provide a lot more detail in the question, to be honest. Tell us what is specified. Formats which change encoding part way through can be a pain to work with - and it'll be very hard to help you without more information.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, sorry, you are right. I think I need to post another question to ask about the parsing a non ASCII line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although untested, I'm sure this will be considerably faster:

```
static IEnumerable<byte[]> fread(string fname, Encoding enc) 
{
  using (var f = File.OpenRead(fname))
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(f, enc))
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      yield return enc.GetBytes(reader.ReadLine());     
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Also I didn't notice the `enc` param!

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this can be so simple. The performance seems about 3 times faster than my freadbytes() function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
static IEnumerable<string> fread(string fname, Encoding enc) 
  using (var f = File.OpenRead(fname))
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(f, enc))
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      yield return enc.GetBytes(reader.ReadLine());     
}
```

Update: Had missed the `enc` param initially.

Comment: Given that the encoding is supplied as a parameter, it might be best to use it. Also, your return type is now incorrect.

Comment: Yeah. I missed it. I got distracted by SO message: 'New answers have been posted' :p